# How to install pip for python 3.3 on Windows?

Tags: pip, python-3.3

I have to install python 3.3.5 particularly to use the api for [OriginPro](https://www.originlab.com/doc/LabTalk/guide/work-with-python#A_Note_to_Use_Python_Extensions). However, when I try to install pip installation manager by downloading the get-pip.py and run it in python from cmd prompt, I get the following error

```
C:\Users\hsurdi\Documents>python get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 21492, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 197, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip._internal
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\hsurdi\appdata\local\temp\tmph5uqmw\pip.zip\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\hsurdi\appdata\local\temp\tmph5uqmw\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\hsurdi\appdata\local\temp\tmph5uqmw\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\hsurdi\appdata\local\temp\tmph5uqmw\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\hsurdi\appdata\local\temp\tmph5uqmw\pip.zip\pip\_internal\utils\hashes.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\hsurdi\appdata\local\temp\tmph5uqmw\pip.zip\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\hsurdi\appdata\local\temp\tmph5uqmw\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
RuntimeError: Python 3.4 or later is required
```

Where/how do I get pip for python 3.3.5?

Comment: Even if you could install `pip` for Python 3.3 — what would you install with that `pip`? Most packages at PyPI now require Python 3.4+, some 3.5+.

Comment: do the basics like numpy, scipy etc need python 3.4+? And I specifically want to install [PyOriginTools](https://github.com/swharden/PyOriginTools)

Answer (score 6):

`pip` dropped support for Python 3.3 at version [18.0](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#id109). `setuptools` (required by `pip`) dropped support for Python 3.3 at version [40.0](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#v4000). So you need to download [`pip 10.0.1`](https://pypi.org/project/pip/10.0.1/#files) and [`setuptools 39.2.0`](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/39.2.0/#files) (source distributions, `*.tar.gz`). Extract the archives and run `python setup.py install` first for `setuptools`, then for `pip`.

As for the latest versions of numpy and scipy, let's us see.

Numpy: https://pypi.org/project/numpy/
Requires: Python >=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, **!=3.3.***

scipy: https://pypi.org/project/scipy/
 Requires: Python **>=3.5**

See? You will need to do research to find out versions compatible with Python 3.3.